# Como criar listas em grade com C# no WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, lista

Sou  novo em C#. Gostaria de saber como criar uma lista em grade que contenha imagens, algo parecido com o que o android tem:

[image: 1]]

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

o conteúdo deve ser colocado dentro de um `ItemsControl`
assim:

```
<ItemsControl 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Tasks, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
            ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
            >
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  
                    AllowDrop="True" 
                    Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=itmWrapPanel}" 
                    Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=itmWrapPanel}"  />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate  >
            <local:ucTask  />  <!-- esse ucTask é um usercontrol com o que será exibido -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

**ucTask**

```
<UserControl x:Class="blablabla.ucTask"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
>
    <Grid Focusable="False" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,5">
            <Image  Source="{Binding Imagem}"  Focusable="False"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Label Content="{Binding Texto}" FontSize="10"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

P.S.: Customizações de posicionamento e/ou alinhamento não estão nesse exemplo, e ficam por sua conta

P.S.2: O `WrapPanel` é quemvai distribuir os itens no seu `ItemsControl` o alinhamento e posicionamento deve ser verificando nele tb